# I want to store large chunk data in true/false format using bits

Tags: c#

Consider example where I have many types(types - some sections). For each type there are multiple values and out of available values possible useful values are less.
each type will store 30 values. All 30 values are not applicatble but I need to store in 1/0 format. Consuming byte is also costly here.
Please guide me on the same.

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting to use a bitfield. Are these values mapping to a Enum? please give us more details (by editing your original question) and explain what you are trying to accomplish ***and why***. Please include some sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: @scott: Exactly, I am having enum of 30 integers.For ex: Enum SectionTYpe { Top,Bottom,..} snd I have Objects which specificaly point to some of the enum integers.Then i need to maintain object and its collection of possible section types. Then from that i want to filter what all section types I can support for the given object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class.

Comment: plz elaborate more by giving example.

Answer (score 0):

You can define either an int column (If you have value less than or equal to 32) or bigint column (long in case C#) (If you have value less than or equal to 64) along with each Type and then define each bit of either int or bigint (long in case C#) column as one value of type and then store.

For Example: Suppose that each type has four value Physics, Maths, Chemistry, English and others up to 32. Now we have a type as "Class" which have only three value Physics, Maths and English and rest is not available. So value will be 0000000000000000000000000001011 = 13.